# Laravel Homestead producing a strange error on boot.Adding entries to host.

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am having an error with Laravel Homestead.

The install was working fine yesterday after re-installing vagrant and VirtualBox. It was previously broken due to VirtualBox thinking there was a VM booted permanently.

Moving onto the issue that has now presented itself.

During boot, I noticed that it's now putting some items into my hosts file that seem like they should definitely not be there.

```
192.168.10.10   homestead   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias ..="cd .."    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias ...="cd ../.."    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias h='cd ~'  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias c='clear' # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias art=artisan   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias phpspec='vendor/bin/phpspec'  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias phpunit='vendor/bin/phpunit'  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   alias serve=serve-laravel   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   function serve-laravel() {  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10       if [[ "$1" && "$2" ]]   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10       then    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo dos2unix /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo bash /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh "$1" "$2" 80    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10       else    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           echo "Error: missing required parameters."  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           echo "Usage: "  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           echo "  serve domain path"  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10       fi  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   }   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   function serve-hhvm() { # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo dos2unix /vagrant/scripts/serve-hhvm.sh    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo bash /vagrant/scripts/serve-hhvm.sh "$1" "$2" 80   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           echo "  serve-hhvm domain path" # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   function serve-proxy() {    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo dos2unix /vagrant/scripts/serve-proxy.sh   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo bash /vagrant/scripts/serve-proxy.sh "$1" "$2" 80  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           echo "  serve-proxy domain port"    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   function serve-apache() {   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo dos2unix /vagrant/scripts/serve-apache.sh  # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           sudo bash /vagrant/scripts/serve-apache.sh "$1" "$2" 80 # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10           echo "  serve-apache domain path"   # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10   function artisan() {    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
192.168.10.10       php artisan "$@"    # VAGRANT: 3be92b85d2bb8cbac75b4b871e8f103f (default) / 20aee27a-1d7a-4f2f-8592-9f65216ed952
```

I can only think that some updates in VirtualBox since i installed it the previous time has caused this error. I am just at a complete loss now as to how to fix it.

The symptoms of this are now that a couple of sites out of my 3 sites provisioned are working fine but one is not.

Here is the contents of my homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\Jay\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\Jay\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: d:/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/homestead.app/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin/
    - map: consumer.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/consumer/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

It is my homestead.app that doesn't work. I think that could be quite important in finding the problem.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First off, homestead.app cannot be a folder. Folders cannot have extensions. Also, make sure you have the consumer folder directly inside of your `d:/code`. Finally, as far as I know you can't use phpmyadmin with homestead. There are plenty of other sql editors you can find online.

Comment: I use phpmyadmin just fine in homestead. I actually have managed to fix this issue and i was about to write an answer, but homestead.app as a folder works fine. I have used folders with extensions for quite some time with no problems on many other projects due to a weird habit i picked up off someone (consumer folder is my attempt to break that habit).

Comment: Well those are the only reasons I can see for having those errors. Are you certain phpmyadmin, homestead.app, and consumer folders are all with your d:/code?

Comment: As I mentioned I fixed the issue and was about to post the fix, turned out to be me trying to route homestead.app to 127.0.0.1 as per a suggestion in another post.

Comment: Although i still don't know why those random host entries are being added